# Add role when logged_in

Tags: users

I want to add a role to the user when they log in for the very first time to their account. Any ideas of how to work this out? Rules maybe?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Rules only with module logintoboggan. Then you will have Event: when user account is active

With custom module hook_user_login and you must check for custom fields filled only once like timestamp.